# How to scroll down on pages in doc-view mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, docview

I have recently started using doc-view in Emacs, but I am having quite a few problems with it. The main one is that I can't scroll down on pages. I can see the next or previous page using "n" or "p", but the commands to scroll up and down a page, which are supposedly SPACE and DEL, do not work. Well, to be fair, DEL works, but it goes to the previous page rather than scroll up to the bottom of the previous page. The result is that I can only see the top of the pdf pages, but not the bottom parts.

I tried changing the view to continuous, but that doesn't work either. This is what I tried changing:

[image]

I did check the customisations for doc-view, but the variables (or options, or whatever they are called) did not appear to me to be the ones which would solve my problem.

More information: I did manage to make SPACE and DEL work at some point, but I don't remember what I did, and I can't get it to work again. I am using Aquamacs.

Any ideas?

By the way, another problem I have is that doc-view causes Aquamacs to sort of crash, meaning it freezes everything, keeps "thinking", and I have to force quit Aquamacs to get it to work again. While this is not my main question, if anyone can tell me anything about this I would also appreciate.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I tried what the answer below suggested, it didn't work, kept trying other things/commands, and then C-n and SPACE started working! I quit Aquamacs, started it again, opened a pdf document, and it is back to not working. Can someone please explain what is happening? How can I make this reliable?

Comment: I guess the developers are aware of this issue.  There was someone who asked a similar question on usenet at gnu.emacs.help (http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/3aafd1508a332b65?pli=1).  Though not sure if they use Aquamacs as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. A quick look and it doesn't seem they were talking specifically about my problem, but I will read other posts on that website and hopefully I will get some answers.

Comment: It seems I found something related to my problem, thanks to your tip, @vpit3833. I will read more carefully, but what I am referring to is here (need to check previous and following threads): http://osdir.com/ml/bug-gnu-emacs-gnu/2009-11/msg00509.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To commands to scroll down are bind to:

**C-n, down**

not **SPC**

*UPDATE:*

**SPC** is rebound in docview mode. Can't reproduce you issue using GNU Emacs/Linux, can you invoke:

```
M-x doc-view-scroll-down-or-previous-page
```

Comment: I will put all my comments in one: 1. The page http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Navigation.html  says SPACE should work.  2. C-n was not working, then suddenly it started working together with SPACE, but once I closed Emacs and opened again, it is back at not working. 3. I "unaccepted" your answer because I want to know how to reliably make scrolling work in  doc-view/Emacs. I can't vote you up for now (because I changed my vote), but I will do it as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: I tried your command and this is what I got: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1885087/doc-view.png . That didn't do much for me, unfortunately. I feel my computer (or my aquamacs) doesn't like doc-view much, and it gets really slow while doc-view is running. I am travelling at the moment, but when I get a chance, hopefully today, I will look into that I get back to you. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

```
(setq doc-view-continuous t)
```

This lets you scroll the whole document with mouse wheel(not just the current page).

Comment: Really bad that this is no preset. Who doesn't want continuous scrolling? :-D